# do-applescript: AppleEvent timed out

Tags: process

Execute this in emacs:

```lisp
(do-applescript "open location \"marginnote3app://note/AEB009E4-0DFB-4B2D-A47D-293018C36116\"")
```

```
do-applescript: AppleEvent timed out.
```

However,

```
osascript -e "open location \"marginnote3app://note/AEB009E4-0DFB-4B2D-A47D-293018C36116\""
```

works.

Why `do-applescript` makes such error?

Comment: I don't know the answer to the question, buy you may wish to trying using using `start-process` and/or `call-process` ... The arguments for would include, but not be limited to:  `shell-file-name` and `shell-command-switch` and `osascript -e ....`

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: `AppleEvent timed out` is a macOS error, `do-applescript` is just reporting what it knows. try wrapping your apple script in a [with timeout](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-DontLinkElementID_897) and see if that helps. double check and triple check your quoting. try other applescript, if that fails too you may be running into issues with Apple's goofy new permissions/restrictions.

Comment: fyi, everything i tried with `do-applescript` (Emacs 28.1, macOS Monterey, admin enabled user) _worksforme_.